# counting a specific value in a column and tabling the results Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that has 10 million rows. I want to count how many times certain numbers occur in the Values column and at the same time create a column of the results. Specifically I want to count how many times does 0 and all the numbers till 100 000 occur in the `Value` Column. Previously I used excel and used the formula `=Countif(A:A,row(a1))`

```
   Values
0  54796
1  78957
2  75894
3  78469
4  26972
5  28446
6  28784
7  55795
8  32698
```

Counting for a specific number is quite simple with the code:

```
df.loc[df.Values == '21288', 'Values'].count()
```

I am afraid to crash my computer before trying the following code thus would ask you to tell if its correct or not.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Hello world')

for index in df.index:
    df['Counts'] = df.loc[df.New_Value == df.loc[index,'New_Value'], 'New_Value'].count()
```

Comment: Check value_counts

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

**Input Data:**

```
>>> df
    Values
0    54796
1    78957
2    75894
3    78469
4    26972
5    28446
6    28784
7    55795
8    32698
9    55795
10   26972
```

**`Value_counts`**:

```
>>> df.Values.value_counts()
#output
26972    2
55795    2
28446    1
78957    1
54796    1
32698    1
75894    1
78469    1
28784    1
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

**Filtering the `value_counts` results**:

```
value_df = df.Values.value_counts().to_frame().astype(int)
#results only below 40000
value_df[value_df.index < 40000]
```

```
       Values
26972       2
28446       1
32698       1
28784       1
```

If you want to add another `Count` column to the **original** dataframe.

```
#creating a dictionary based on the value counts
>>> d = df.Values.value_counts().to_dict()

#mapping the count to the Values columns
>>> df['Count'] = df.Values.map(d)
```

**Output**:

```
    Values  Count
0    54796      1
1    78957      1
2    75894      1
3    78469      1
4    26972      2
5    28446      1
6    28784      1
7    55795      2
8    32698      1
9    55795      2
10   26972      2
```

Confirmation with your method:

```
>>> df.loc[df.Values == 26972, 'Values'].count()
2
>>> df.loc[df.Values == 55795, 'Values'].count()
2
```

**For your `V100.csv`**:

```
df = pd.read_csv('V100.csv',delimiter=',')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).dropna()
df = df.astype(int)

print(df['Fives'].value_counts())
print(df.loc[df.Fives == 9100, 'Fives'].count())
```

```
9100     2445
9200     2401
100      2394
1100     2350
8200     2315
         ...
43855     862
33866     860
74277     858
47922     857
53011     834
Name: Fives, Length: 9910, dtype: int64

2445
```

Notice that counts for `9100` are the same.

Comment: Not sure. Let me take for example counting  `54796` from my given example. There is only one of it so it should return 1. But the results are not the same if I use `df.loc[df.Fives == '54796', 'Fives'].count()`.  The two return different count numbers in my real data. Dont know if either the problem occurs with element types.

Comment: I am sure `value_counts` is not gonna give wrong results. I will try your way on another small test df.

Comment: Added an update to answer to show the results are identical.

Comment: Counting on the column called `Fives`

Comment: I would need access to that link. You can try few things: first, try converting df to int datatype with `df = df.astype(int)`. Also, try counting as `df.loc[df.Fives == 54796, 'Fives'].count()` . Notice that I have remove quotes of the number.

Comment: Retry, I have removed access. I will try those. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223310/discussion-between-grayrigel-and-moshe).

Comment: Added the update based on your  CSV. I hope it helps. Please don't forget to upvote and accept.

Comment: I have added follow ups on the chat please check them

Comment: Added a detailed explanation for you. Hope it helps